# remove button shadow?

Tags: android, button

Inside my app, if the button's background has a corner radius, then you can see the shadow behind it, and I am trying to remove that shadow.

I have tried:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
android:shadowRadius="0"
```

But none of them works.

As you can see from the picture, the shadow is very light but visible, especially at the bottom left and right corners.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextView`  instead of `Button`. and set `background` and `clickListener` for your `TextView`. and u will never have this `shadow` .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set a shadow color of transparent. 
But I am not sure it will be work. 
Hope can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use style .

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"></style>
```